# JavaScript Booking System Submit Button not working

Tags: javascript, html

We are making a booking system. All the information that the user types will be saved in a file. Everything works beside the submit button...

```
<input
    type="text"
    name="SocialUsername"
    id="Username"
    placeholder="Username I can contact you on"
/>
<div>
    <input
        type="button"
        id="submitbtn"
        value="Book"
        onclick="saveFile()"
    />
</div>
```

Comment: I just posted the part with the submit button and saveFile() function

Comment: Did you check the console? Can you add the `saveFile()` function to your question?

Comment: You don't have a submit button, you have a button-button which calls a JS function  you haven't shared with us. You need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: let saveFile = () => {
      // Get the data from each element on the form.
      const fname = document.getElementById("fname");
      const lname = document.getElementById("lname");

Comment: Don't post it as comment; [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65071209/edit) your question. Post all relevant code, and check your console for error messages.

Comment: Also, getting this to "work" is extremely trivial: https://jsfiddle.net/7b94zf2r/. You are a full stack developer, so it's probably not that simple. Make sure to post all relevant code and give a detailed error description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**type attribute in input tag should be set as "submit"**

```
<input
    type="text"
    name="SocialUsername"
    id="Username"
    placeholder="Username I can contact you on"
  />
  <div>
    <input
      type="submit"
      id="submitbtn"
      value="Book"
      onclick="saveFile()"
    />
  </div>
</div>
```

**Or you could even go for button tags**

```
<input
    type="text"
    name="SocialUsername"
    id="Username"
    placeholder="Username I can contact you on"
  />
  <div>
    <button type="submit" id="submitbtn" value="Book" onclick="saveFile()">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can i maybe send you my full code. I am new to this so I dont know how to post the full one

Comment: How can i write you and send it?

Comment: check out [codepn.io](https://codepen.io/) put your html,css,javascript code there and whatever you want and any other problem faced in the comments and share the link here

Comment: dude u missing form tag action attribute and manythings like css and php check them out or give all your code and you did not even put it in the comments your proper problem